# Performance of INSERT vs INSERT /*+ direct */

Tags: vertica

Which directive `INSERT` or `INSERT /*+ direct */` has a smallest insertion time? Why?

Answer (score 6):

When you use the DIRECT hint the INSERT statement will by-pass the Write Optimised Store (WOS - in memory) and write directly to disc into the Read Optimised Store (ROS).

So...

- the single INSERT without DIRECT could be faster but it depends on several configuration parameter and the WOS status
- even if you insert in the WOS - sooner or later - a Vertica process (Tuple Mover) will have to move data to disc (ROS).